# how to instantly change image on button click without rerendering component

Tags: react-native, image, react-functional-component

i have 3 images and on button click I am changing those one by one but after I click the button a white screen is shown than the new image is shown how can I instantly change images without any delay. you can check out my output
[video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g5u5aNJrPdMTVvEY4m9jkz4cG9RGAtSH/view?usp=sharing)

my code:

```
export const Start = ({ navigation }) => {

const [image, setImage] = useState(images.start_1)
const [text, setText] = useState("Discover the\nmost beautiful\nroads in the\nworld")
const [count, setCount] = useState(1)

useEffect(() => {
    if (count == 2) {
        setImage(images.start_2)
        setText("Make a road trip\nthrough fantastic\nlandscapes.")
    }
    else if (count == 3) {
        setImage(images.start_3)
        setText("Share your\nunique experiences\nwith others.")
    }
    else if (count == 4) {
        navigation.replace('home')
    }
}, [count])

return (
    <ImageBackground
        resizeMode='stretch'
        source={image}
        defaultSource={images.start_1}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text style={{
            fontSize: 30,
            color: 'white',
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: 120,
            left: 20
        }}>{text}
        </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
            activeOpacity={0.8}
            onPress={() => setCount(count + 1)}
            style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                bottom: 55,
                right: 20
            }}>
            <ImageBackground
                resizeMode='cover'
                source={images.button}
                style={{
                    paddingVertical: 5,
                    paddingHorizontal: 40,
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center'
                }}
                imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 20 }}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, color: 'white' }}>Start</Text>
            </ImageBackground>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </ImageBackground>
)
```

}

Comment: Are the images local on the device/in the bundle, or are they fetched over the network?

Comment: local in the bundle

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an image from over the network, I'd probably recommend against using `ImageBackground` and instead try to use React Native's `Image` component or [React Native Fast Image](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image). Both `Image` and `FastImage` allow you to prefetch specific images - so they are in the cache before being used/shown to a user.

Alternatively, you could try embedding the images in the app/bundle and see if that gives you the same loading delay/flash.